# Determining a constant from two equations

Tags: material-science

I am an engineering undergraduate taking a materials science module and i am having some trouble with the mathematical execution of the following question:

Determine the constant in the equation for creep-rate:

$$\epsilon_{ss} = Ce^{\frac{-Q}{RT}} $$

at a stress of 100Mpa for the stainless steel. The activation energy, Q, is equal to 341,1 kJ/mol. R = 8.314J/mol.K and it is observed from the map that $\epsilon_{ss} $= $10^{-8}$ at $495^{\circ}$C and $\epsilon_{ss} $= $10^{--4}$ at $655^{\circ}$C

My attempt at the problem:

It is clear that we will need to solve for the constant C by means of simultaneous equations. Let us simplify the equation by taking $ln$ of both sides:

$$\ln(\epsilon_{ss}) = \ln(C) - \frac{Q}{RT}$$

In another similar example, the temperature was kept constant and the question asked to solve for two variables - this meant the two constants could be easily solved for by subtracting the two equations hence cancelling the one constant, solving for the remaining one and substituting back in to solve for the other. However, in this case i've tried adding, subtracting and dividing the equations and i either end up cancelling C, which i am trying to solve for or i get some strange answers.

Any hints on how to solve this type of setup would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Treat C like a variable, separate it, and solve for it directly.  Just remember to watch the units.

Comment: Wait, don't you know everything in the equation except for the single variable `C`?  I.e. you know $Q$ and $R$, and you are given  $\epsilon_{ss}$ and $T$... so you can solve for `C` with just a single equation?

Comment: Remember to convert T to degrees K and remember that Q is given in kJ/mol.  Plugging and chugging the known data into the log equation above for each temperature gives the same result for C, so the data you are given is apparently consistent.

Answer (score 1):

For the equation $\epsilon_{ss} = Ce^{\frac{-Q}{RT}}$ it appears that you know $Q, R$ and you have some experimental values (well at least two!) for $\epsilon_{ss}$ and $T$. The usual way to determine the constant $C$ is to take logarithms of both sides giving (as you have noted) $\ln(\epsilon_{ss}) = \ln(C) - \frac{Q/R}{T}$ and to plot $\ln(\epsilon_{ss})$ against $1/T$. This is an equation of the form $y = mx + c$ and so your experimental results should fall on a straight line with gradient $-\frac{Q}{R}$ and intercept $\ln C$.